# Unable to make android build

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-manifest

I am working on an ionic project. I am trying to make a build using 'ionic cordova build android'. Until last night I was able to make the build easily. But since, this morning I am getting error below. I have tried solution available online for android native. But it's not working. Please help.

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-31:19 to override.

Comment: Try running npm install and then build it.

Comment: Also, sad but true, try restarting your machine.

Comment: No man...these all things I have tried. Nothing worked. It's happening because of google's firebase update on 17th june.

Comment: Need to migrate the project to androidx. Migration can easily be done in android studio. But I have no idea how to do it in VS code.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Look at the solution that I have given @Francesco

Comment: thanks @ShubhamAnand, but It's not working yet. I get: 'FirebasePlugin.java:436: error: cannot find symbol'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because if you are using android firebase dependencies in your project then you need to migrate into androidx. This can be done easily using Android Studio but I am developing my project using VS Code.

I tried running below given commands and the bug got fixed:

```sh
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Comment: thanks   but It's not working yet. I get: 'FirebasePlugin.java:436: error: cannot find symbol'